# Format date in Visual basic

Tags: vba, date

I would like to get today's date in the following format: `mmddyyyy`. 
Even if it's first of August I still want zeros in front, like so: `08012012`.

I think I can use DatePart function for it, but I am not sure how.
Anyone has an idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not say which application, but in VBA, you can say:

```
 Format(date(),"mmddyyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Application.Text(Date(),"mmddyyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Format(NOW,"mmddyyyy")
```

NOW gives time as well:

```
Format(NOW,"hh:mm:ss")
```